# How to find function $f$ in this equation: $f^2(2u+9v)=f^9(2u^2+9v^9)+2019u^2v^9$

Tags: functions

I don't know how to start to solve this problem.

Is it possible to find function in this equation?

How to find all functions $f$ that satisfy:
$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$f^2(2u+9v)=f^9(2u^2+9v^9)+2019u^2v^9 \:\:\: \forall\: u,v \: \in \: \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: The number $2019$ appears, raising the doubt that this is from a contest held this year. I don't really doubt anything, but can you give a link to the origin, please? Just to still my fears that this might be from a currently on-going contest? Answering such would be against a site policy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know. maybe it's be a question in a contest. But I think it was for Vietnam. I saw it in a Romanian magazine.

Comment: OK. If it be one question of a contest, I'll delete this question.

Comment: FWIW I would check what the substitution $u\mapsto -u$ does.

Comment: In my opinion there is no such function. First, setting $u=0$, we find that $f^9(9v^9)\ge 0$, hence $f(9v^9)\ge 0$ and so $f\ge 0$. Second, $f^2(9v+2u) = f^2(9v-2u)$ for all $u,v$. Taking the square root, $f(x+y) = f(x-y)$ for all $x,y$. But this means that $f$ is constant. But a constant function can never satisfy the equation for all $u,v$.

Comment: @amsmath For last part, you replaced $u$ with $-u$ ?

Comment: @BarzanHayati Does $f^n$ mean the $n$th power of $f$ or $f$ applied $n$ times?

Comment: @Allawonder It's means power. derivatives write in ()

Comment: @BarzanHayati Allawonder's question was not about power vs derivative but about power vs composition.

Comment: I don't know what's your response about "composition"

Comment: @BarzanHayati Are you saying that brackets here denote derivatives. If so, derivatives with respect to what?

Comment: @Allawonder No. $f^2=f.f$

Comment: @BarzanHayati Yes, I now understand that. I was asking about your reference to $()$ denoting differentiation. Is this the case? If so, what are you differentiating with respect to?

Comment: Another question: Does $f^2(2u+9v),$ for example, mean $(f(2u+9v))^2,$ or $f^2×(2u+9v)$?

Comment: @Allawonder $2u+9v$ is input argument of $f$. So if $2u+9v=10$ then $f(10)$ will be calculated then power to $2$